# Cypress - selecting drop down options does not add the expected items to the list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, cypress

I have a drop down to select multiple items from the options which should add the items chosen to the text/tag/display field. The drop down options only closes when user clicks outside the options. else it stays put waiting for next input(So i am simulating a click on the label of the drop down once i chose all the options). However the chosen items are not added to the tag/text field.

Manually clicking on the item on the page adds them. Only via cypress its not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ProqG.png) As you see on the attached image the selected items are added above. This is performed on the website manually.

The below is the code that i am trying with.  labelField is the variable that holds the selector for "Permission(s)" label. userDetails.permission object key holds options to be chosen. Note: I have tried with cy.click() params like timeout and waitforanimation. Also used .trigger("click").

```
cy.wrap(labelField.next()).find('.multiselect__select').click();
cy.wrap(labelField.next()).within(() => {
    userDetails.permission.forEach(($item) => {
        cy.get('.multiselect__element').contains($item).click({ timeout: 2000 });
    });
});
cy.wrap(labelField).click();  // click on label to hide the options after choosing required items.
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using [Vue Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org).

I can't tell exactly what is going wrong with your code, because a lot of detail is hidden inside custom selectors which are omitted from the question.

Probably the key thing that is missing from the test is an **assertion** at each step of the loop.

Here's a runnable example that includes some assertions to check after each click().

```js
Cypress.config('scrollBehavior', 'center')       // put the action in the center 

// A custom command just to make the assertion more readable
Cypress.Commands.add('eachText', {prevSubject: true}, ($els) => {
  return [...$els].map(e => e.innerText)
})

it('tests multiselect', () => {

  cy.visit('https://vue-multiselect.js.org/')

  // taking the "Tagging" example
  cy.contains('label', 'Tagging').next('div.multiselect').within(() => {

    // assert "Javascript" is the only item selected initially
    cy.get('span.multiselect__tag').eachText()
      .should('deep.eq', ['Javascript'])

    // click an item
    cy.get('div.multiselect__select').click()
    cy.contains('li.multiselect__element', 'Open Source').click()

    // assert the list has two items
    cy.get('span.multiselect__tag').eachText()
      .should('deep.eq', ['Javascript', 'Open Source'])

    // click another
    cy.get('div.multiselect__select').click()
    cy.contains('li.multiselect__element', 'Vue.js').click()

    // assert we have three items
    cy.get('span.multiselect__tag').eachText()
      .should('deep.eq', ['Javascript', 'Open Source', 'Vue.js'])
  })
})
```

[image]